# What is the proper namespace for IPHostEntry and DNS?

Tags: c#, .net

My program uses IPHostEntry and DNS, i know i have to add System.Object, System.Net.IPHostEntry, System.Net.DNS to my project reference but i can not find it in the list.

After the System.IO.Log the next to follow is System. Management (no System.Object)

After the System.Net is System.Numerics (no System.Net.IPHostEntry or System.Net.DNS)

I am using .NET 4.0

What do i do to add the following reference and make it work?

i have the following codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
    public string LocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }
```

Comment: `System.Object` is not a namespace. It's a class. Who told you to add such a reference? What is the problem now? Does you code not compile?

Comment: i cant add system.object somehow when i add it the object turns blue with red squiggly line

Comment: Ok i think i got it Caps "O" on object is the problem... sorry for the trouble sir.

Comment: You only need `System.Net` (for `IPHostEntry` and `Dns` classes) and `System.Net.Sockets` (for `AddressFamily` enumeration) for the code to compile....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes belong to *assemblies* and exist in *namespaces*.

You *reference* assemblies. You specify classes in your code by using their full name (namespace + class name) or you can add certain namespaces in [`using` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

So you need to find, from the documentation, where each class belongs and then ensure that you're referencing those assemblies:

[`IPHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.aspx) and [`Dns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) belong to the `System.Net` namespace and are in the `System` assembly.

[`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) belongs to the `System` namespace and is in `mscorlib`.

You almost certainly already have references to these assemblies. But you might want to add `using` directives at the head of your code file.

---

Add:

```
using System.Net;
```

to your `using` directives (you already have a `using System;` for referring to `Object`)

Comment: Posting code in comments doesn't tend to work well, since it's unformatted. This would be better edited back into your question. But by the look of things, whilst you have two `using`s for namespaces *inside* `System.Net`, you don't have one just for `System.Net`.