# "using namespace" problems on DNS and AddressFamily

Tags: c#, .net

'm a newbie in C# normally my forte is C++ and VB. I have 2 problem in which i have commented on the code:

1.) Blue squiggle lines appear on the 3 Uses it say ""A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Object' ... "

2.) i could not get an output IP address from my variable LocalIP in which i declared as public.

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

//Blue squiggly line appear on this 2 Uses
using Dns = System.Net.Dns;
using AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class frm_Log : Form
{
    public String localIP;

    public string LocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        //string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }

    ....
    ....

    // variable localIP.Trim() does not giveout any output
    MyValue="LogAccept,"+this.txt_UserName.Text.Trim()+","+this.txt_Password.Text.Trim() + "," + localIP.Trim() ;

    ....
    ....
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the line where you expect localip to be set?

Comment: I generally write code with the class names in the editor and then when Visual Studio cannot resolve a name if you click on the name that cannot be resolved and press Ctrl + . (that is the control key plus the period symbol), then a context menu will come up with suggestions of possible using statements to be added to the file. If Visual Studio cannot find a match, then it usually means that you do  not have the assembly (DLL) referenced in your project or you are trying to use a class that you have not written yet (that is for any custom classes you intend to use).

Comment: By the way, nice job on asking a good question; posted code and explained what you tried to do and why you were stuck. Makes helping people that much easier. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding System.Object, System.Net.IPHostEntry, System.Net.DNS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269738/adding-system-object-system-net-iphostentry-system-net-dns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Object` is a class. `System` is the namespace, which you already have defined as the first `using` at the top of the file.

Comment: Same is true with .DNS and .AddressFamily

Comment: @sous2817 - yes, I was hoping that was implied, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Karl - I haven't been here that long, but long enough to know that there was probably a follow up comment along the lines of "okay, what about the other two".

Comment: @sous2817 - understood :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx suggests this syntax:

```
using Dns = System.Net.Dns;
```

The standard version of using (`using System.Linq;`) can only target namespaces, not classes in a namespace. If you have imported a whole namespace, though, you don't need to specifically import anything in it.

Comment: still have blue squiggly line and still no output on my Local Ip variable

Comment: @Henryyottabyte `using System.Object;` -> System.Object is not a namespace. The error message should be informing you of this.

Comment: @Henryyottabyte 'squiggly' is not a very formal term, by the way - call them syntax errors or compile time errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Original Code was

```
using System
....
using System.Object;
using System.Net.Dns;
using System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily;
....
```

resolution

```
//using System.Object --> since uses system already defined.
using Dns = System.Net.Dns;
using AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily;
```